# In Java 8 '+' operator for concatinating replaced by new StringBuilder()

Tags: java, string, optimization, stringbuilder

In Java 8, I wrote some sample code.

```
String s1 = "Hello";  
String s2 = "world";  
String s3 = s1 + s2;
```

After decompiling .class file I found that 3rd statement

```
 String s3 = s1 + s2;
```

replaced by

```
 String s3 = new StringBuilder(s1).append(s2).toString();
```

Does it mean that There is no longer need to use explicit StringBuilder for Optimization and just use '+' operator instead of?

Comment: "*Does it mean that There is no longer need to use explicit StringBuilder*" - No, javac uses it in such trivial cases only. In a loop, you still need to use `StringBuilder` youself.

Comment: Yes It is right, I wrote some sample program and decompile it and got to know that in loop we need StringBuilder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Actually, this optimization had been done in Java 6. See Bruce Eckel's "Thinking in Java" 4th edition pp.356-359 for details